# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE - Lock wait time out

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, insert-update

I am struggling with `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for a file on a big InnoDB table.

My `values` table saves the details for each entity belonging to an client. An entity can have only one value for a particular key. So when a change is happening we are updating the same. The table looks something like below:

```
CREATE TABLE `key_values` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'customer/tenant id',
  `key_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'reference to the keys',
  `entity_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` text,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `client_id` (`client_id`,`entity_id`,`key_id`),
  KEY `client_id_2` (`client_id`,`key_id`)
) ;
```

All writes queries are of the form:

```
INSERT INTO `key_values` 
  (client_id, key_id, entity_id,value)
values
  (23, 47, 147, 'myValue'), (...), (...)...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = values(value);
```

- The table is around 350M records by now and is growing pretty fast.
- The writes to table can happen from real time integration often
  inserting less than 10 rows or as a bulk of 25K from offline sources.
- For a given client, only one bulk operation can run at a time. This is reduce the row locks between `insert`
- Lock wait time out period is set at 50 seconds

Currently, when the offline activities are happening sometimes(not always) we are getting an lock wait time-out. What could be possible changes without to avoid the time out ?

- A design change at the moment is not possible ( sharding/partitioning/cluster).
- `REPLACE` is another candidate, but I dont want to give delete privilege in production to anything from code.
- `INSERT IGNORE` and then `UPDATE` is a good candidate, but will it give much improvement?

What other options do I have?

Thanks in advance for all suggestion and answers.

Comment: Try to increase `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` variable in your session from default 50 seconds to much more. See this link for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout  When other connections place locks on rows in the table, your query is blocked and must wait for others to complete, and when the total waiting time exceeded 50 seconds, you will get `lock wait time out` error. Alternatively you can optimize other long running queries that hold locks for a time > 50 seconds, but this may not be practical.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the lock wait timeout, this can be changed via the mysql configuration setting [innodb_lock_wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) which can be modified dynamically (without restarting mysql), in addition to changing it in your my.cnf.

Regarding the lock waits, one thing to consider with mysql is the default transaction isolation level, which is REPEATABLE READ. The side effect of this setting is that much more locking occurs for reads that you might expect (especially if you had a SQL Server background, which has a default tran iso level of READ COMMITTED). Now, if you don't need REPEATABLE READ, you can change your tran iso level, either in a query, using the SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL syntax, or for the whole server, using the config setting [transaction-isolation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_transaction-isolation). I recommend using READ COMMITTED, and consider if there are other places in your application where even 'dirtier' reads are acceptable (in which case you can use READ UNCOMMITTED.

Comment: Increasing lock wait time out wont permanent solution, we might need to keep on increasing as and when lock wait time out happens. 
Will have try more with isolation level. The offline process I mentioned can be even more than 30 minutes and is within single transaction. I will definitely give a try and will update here

Comment: Yes, a 30 minute transaction that grabs exclusive locks on ranges of rows definitely has the potential to block readers unless you lower the tran iso level. I think this note may also make it clear (from the docs): 

"INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE differs from a simple INSERT in that an exclusive next-key lock rather than a shared lock is placed on the row to be updated when a duplicate-key error occurs." 

Even though the docs also state that REPEATABLE READ does "consistent non-locking reads" in practice this is not always the case (especially in the lock escalation scenario described).

Comment: But my lock wait time out happens on bulk `INSERT` query not the `SELECT`. `SELECT` queries should not acquire a lock and SINGLE row INSERT should be fast. I am not sure who can acquire the lock. Also, I always has UNIQUE row identifier and it would be locking only the exact rows, in the case of REPEATABLE READ, right?

Comment: Well, not exactly. MySQL InnoDb does next-key (and sometimes gap) locking, which are not a single record locks. Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html

Comment: I am passing the unique identifier for the row in each `INSERT`. Record lock should work now, right?

Comment: Not always -- you can't force MySQL to use record locking.